# data on the quarterly and monthly world economic growth

Tags: gdp, economic-growth, data-request, data-sources

I would be extremely grateful if you could assist me in acquiring access to dependable and current data regarding global economic growth or GDP growth rates, both at the quarterly and monthly levels. The annual world economic growth data is provided [here](https://www.imf.org/external/datamapper/NGDP_RPCH@WEO/OEMDC/ADVEC/WEOWORLD).

Comment: GDP is typically not collected at monthly frequency so that part is impossible. Also, while some countries have quarterly GDP numbers I don't believe enough countries do it to calculate it for world

Answer (score 0):

For GDP growth, you can find quarterly data directly from each country's central bank. For the US, see the FRED website. For other countries, the one I know of is the OECD statistics site.
GDP does not provide monthly data; instead, the Industrial Production Index is a good proxy. You can find that data from the above sources as well. Note that the Industrial Production Index is not the same as GDP.